# What do you do if an attacker is a trained fighter?

Tags: streetfight

So what do you do if an attacker is under the influence of drugs, he can't listen and hear anything, and you have no choice but to fight. What if your attacker is a trained fighter and you have absolutely no choice but to fight- there is no talking your way out of it or running away- you are cornered. Even worse, you are not a good fighter. How do you survive this situation?

Comment: Offer the druggie more drugs. Offer the martial arts expert an authentic samurai sword. Point to somewhere, and then when they're distracted looking for it, run away. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your question basically comes down to: if you have absolutely no chance, what do you do? It is hard to come up with a serious answer for that and I was close to casting a close vote as this is highly hypothetical, but decided to answer with general advice for self-defense of the defenseless.

The standard advice is twofold:

1. Scream "FIRE" at the top of your voice. Nobody will react when you scream help as people tend to try to avoid getting themselves into something, but fire is inciting...reactions. Raising attention is the best safeguard for situations where fighting is hopeless as people don't like witnesses.
2. Cover vital parts (head, abdomen) as well as possible and do not fight back. Even if they are mad, most people let go of people who do nothing in return.

As you can see, both advices are not particularly 'martial' or give you an edge in a fight. But tbh, you ruled out that there is a fighting chance, thus the best thing you can do is anything that improves your chance of survival or at least not sustaining lasting damage.

Comment: You forgot: Laughing and then yelling a 10 second countdown while crouching down and sticking your fingers in your ears. They may be crazy, but that's Predator stuff. Better get out of there. Someone has a suitcase nuke about to go off. :)